# How to make following iif function deliver given results?

Tags: excel, vba, iif

If activecell.offset(-1,0).value is a text i.e. "slno"

```
IIf(isnumeric(activecell.offset(-1,0).value),activecell.offset(-1,0).value+1,1)
```

This codedelivers run time error 13 type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

The [Help File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1012957)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) for `IIF` states:

> IIf always evaluates both truepart and falsepart, even though it
> returns only one of them. Because of this, you should watch for
> undesirable side effects. For example, if evaluating falsepart results
> in a division by zero error, an error occurs even if expr is True.

So it's trying to evaluate text+value and returning the error.

You'll need to split your `IIF` into an `IF`

```
If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
    a = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) + 1
Else
    a = 1
End If
```

**Edit:**
I guess you could use

```
IIf(IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value), ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, 0) + 1
```

This will return the number or 0 in the `IIF` so no errors there, and then add 1 to it.

Comment: Good answer. Many people use `IIF` because they are used to the IF worksheet function and think that they have the same behaviour. Other people think it is faster, which is not the case because both true and false parts are evaluated as you have mentioned.